# Visual Studio 2015 Web Application very slow request responses

Tags: visual-studio, request, response

I'm having a bit of problem debugging in VS for our web application, basically all requests are painfully slow, requests that used to take <1s are taking over 15s which as you can imagine makes developing a nightmare!
This is on my newly installed laptop (done it twice recently and the problem is the same both times on both laptops).
I've tried the following without success:

- Run without debugging (ctrl+F5)
- Run in release mode
- Disable diagnostics panel in VS
- Disable unused debugging options in VS
- Different browsers (Chrome, FF, Edge)
- Disable Antivirus
- Disable ReSharper/Uninstalled

The solution is a mix of WebForms, MVC, WebAPI, Classic ASP with standard SQL connections (calling stored procs) and Entity Framework.

I have also tried Visual Studio 2017 and I'm getting the same issue there too.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing it? I've googled and tried several things people have suggested without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was down to have the `Data Source` value of the connection string set to (local), where as on my old laptop I know that in some instances this was set to the computer name.

I'm not sure which connection string was a fault as we have several in a fair few config files (about 20 connection strings in total) and I just changed them all.

However I'm still unsure why there is a noticeable difference in using computer name and (local) in this situation.